# Acessing elements from AMAZON XML API in Excel VBA

Tags: xml, excel, amazon-web-services, xml-parsing, vba

I am trying to parse data from Amazon Product Advertising API XML response. I am using DOMDocument in excel vba to load the xml document and parse the resposne. This is how the XML response looks like:

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<OperationRequest>
<RequestId>fd9f1314-29932-45a0-8fc4-c999276425f4</RequestId>
<RequestProcessingTime>0.0265880000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<Items>
<Request>
<IsValid>True</IsValid>
<ItemLookupRequest>
<IdType>ASIN</IdType>
<ItemId>B00CSDILZI</ItemId>
<ResponseGroup>Offers</ResponseGroup>
<VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
</ItemLookupRequest>
</Request>
<Item>
<ASIN>B00CSDILZI</ASIN>
<OfferSummary>
<LowestNewPrice>
<Amount>26761</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>$267.61</FormattedPrice>
</LowestNewPrice>
<TotalNew>22</TotalNew>
<TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
<TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
<TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
</OfferSummary>
<Offers>
<TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers>
<TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
MoreOffersUrl>...</MoreOffersUrl>
<Offer>
<OfferAttributes>...</OfferAttributes>
<OfferListing>
<OfferListingId>...</OfferListingId>
<Price>
<Amount>26761</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>$267.61</FormattedPrice>
</Price>
<AmountSaved>
<Amount>23841</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>$238.41</FormattedPrice>
</AmountSaved>
<PercentageSaved>47</PercentageSaved>
<Availability>Usually ships in 1-2 business days</Availability>
<AvailabilityAttributes>
<AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType>
<MinimumHours>24</MinimumHours>
<MaximumHours>48</MaximumHours>
</AvailabilityAttributes>
<IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
</OfferListing>
</Offer>
</Offers>
</Item>
</Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

I am trying to loop through the entire xml and extract item details like ASIN, FormattedPrice, Lowest price etc to a excel sheet. This is how I tried:

```
Sub subReadXMLStream()

Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xEmpDetails As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xParent As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim Col, Row As Integer

Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
' use XML string to create a DOM, on error show error message
If Not xmlDoc.Load("E:\web\offersumm.xml") Then
    Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set xEmpDetails = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
Set xParent = xEmpDetails.FirstChild
Row = 1
Col = 1

Dim xmlNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList

Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Item")
For Each xParent In xmlNodeList
    For Each xChild In xParent.ChildNodes
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Row, Col).Value = xChild.Text
        Debug.Print Row & " - "; Col & " -  " & xChild.Text
        Col = Col + 1
    Next xChild
    Row = Row + 1
    Col = 1
Next xParent
```

End Sub

However This is printing the entire text in the tags as a  like

```
1 - 1 -  B00CSDILZI
1 - 2 -  26761 USD $267.61 22 0 0 0
1 - 3 -  1 1 ... ... ... 26761 USD $267.61 23841 USD $238.41 47 Usually ships in 1-2 business days now 24 48 0
```

But what I am trying to achieve is get elements by its tag name and the print then in cells. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: How shall the Excel sheet look like? In your code with the given XML the first `xChild` is an `ASIN` element. This is simple, OK. But the second  `xChild` is an `OfferSummary` element which is an complex element itself. It has childs its own. Its first child is an `LowestNewPrice` element which also is an complex element. So how shall this complex structure be placed in the Excel sheet?

Comment: Actually I am not trying to print out each elements. I am interested in only few parameters like ASIN, FormattedPrice, Availability etc and print it in excel columns . That is why I was looking for a way to individually access elements inside the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gets the `ASIN`,  `Offers/Offer[0]/OfferListing/Price/FormattedPrice` and `Offers/Offer[0]/OfferListing/Availability` for each `Item` element in the XML. It supposes there are multiple `Offer` elements possible in `Offers`but only one `OfferListing` in each `Offer`. If there are multiple `Offer` elements, it will get the first.

The syntax using in `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` is XPath, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath. For MSXML2.DOMDocument see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923288.aspx

```
Sub subReadXMLStream()

Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xEmpDetails As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xParent As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim lCol, lRow As Long

Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False

If Not xmlDoc.Load("P:\offersumm.xml") Then
    Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set xEmpDetails = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
Set xParent = xEmpDetails.FirstChild
lRow = 1
lCol = 1

Dim xmlNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList

Dim sFormattedPrice As String, sAvailability As String

Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Item")
For Each xParent In xmlNodeList
    For Each xChild In xParent.ChildNodes
        If xChild.nodeName = "ASIN" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = xChild.Text
            lCol = lCol + 1
        ElseIf xChild.nodeName = "Offers" Then
            sFormattedPrice = xChild.SelectSingleNode("Offer[0]/OfferListing/Price/FormattedPrice").Text
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = sFormattedPrice
            lCol = lCol + 1
            sAvailability = xChild.SelectSingleNode("Offer[0]/OfferListing/Availability").Text
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = sAvailability
            lCol = lCol + 1
        End If
    Next xChild
    lRow = lRow + 1
    lCol = 1
Next xParent

End Sub
```